# Sockets server2server connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

Sockets unlike HTTP doesn't have anything that is `req, res` it is always like:

```
client.on('data', function(data)...
```

Event gets executed when there is data on the stream.

Now I want to do a Server 2 Server communication. I'm writing a game where I am gonna have a main server and this main server communicates with the games desktop client.

One server is a World server and the other is a Login server. The client directly connects to the world server and if the data is a login data then the world server passes it to the login server.

But I cant wrap my head around how to do this in node. As a previous webdev I can only think of:

```
login.send(dataToSendToOtherServer, function(responseOfOtherServer) {
   if (responseOfOtherServer === 1)
     client.write(thisDataIsGoingToTheDesktopClient)
})
```

So how can I do something like this for the sockets in node.js?

I tried something like:

```
Client.prototype.send = function(data, cb) {
  // convert json to string
  var obj = JSON.stringify(data)
  this.client.write(obj)

  // wait for the response of this request
  this.client.on('data', function(req) {
    var request = JSON.parse(req)

    // return response as callback
    if (data.type === request.type) cb(request)
  })

}
```

But with this every request the response gets +1.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dealing with plain TCP/IP, you need to come up with your own higher-level protocol to specify things like how to determine when a message is complete (since TCP offers no guarantee it will all arrive in one gulp). Common ways of dealing with this are:

- Fixed-length messages: buffer up received data until it's the right length.
- Prefixing each message with a length count: buffer up received data until the specified length has been reached.
- Designating some character or sequence as an end-of-message indicator: buffer up received data until it ends with that sequence/character.

In your case, you could buffer up received data until `JSON.parse` succeeds on the accumulated data, assuming each message consists of legal JSON.

Comment: Yes my packets have the total length of the packet at the first byte. What can I do with this now?

Comment: Actually the json part is just example. My real data is a buffer. Protobuf.

Comment: Or do you think something like RPC or a queue where all servers read from the queue is a way of communicating between them, better? I just found those while searching though, I haven't ever tried those nor am I familiar with those.